# How do I create a Lock (concurrent.locks.Lock) in Android?

Tags: java, android, locking

This must be really obvious, but I can't spot the answer. I need to put a lock around a variable to ensure that a couple of race-hazard conditions are avoided. From what I can see, a pretty simple solution exists using Lock, according to the android docs:

```
Lock l = ...;
l.lock();
try {
    // access the resource protected by this lock
 }
 finally {
     l.unlock();
 }
```

So far, so good. However, I can't make the first line work. It would seem that something like:

```
Lock l = new Lock();
```

Might be correct, but eclipse reports, "Cannot instantiate the type Lock" - and no more.

Any suggestions?

Comment: google: java synchronized block

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you're very keen on using a `Lock`, you need to choose a `Lock` implementation as you *cannot* instantiate interfaces.
As per the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/locks/Lock.html)
You have 3 choices:

- [ReentrantLock](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html)
- [Condition](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/locks/Condition.html) This isn't a Lock itself but rather a helper class since `Condition`s are bound to `Lock`s.
- [ReadWriteLock](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReadWriteLock.html)

You're probably looking for the `ReentrantLock` possibly with some `Condition`s

This means that instead of `Lock l = new Lock();` you would do:

```
ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock();
```

However, if all you're needing to lock is a small part, a synchronized block/method is cleaner (as suggested by @Leonidos & @assylias).

If you have a method that sets the value, you can do:

```
public synchronized void setValue (var newValue)
{
  value = newValue;
}
```

or if this is a part of a larger method:

```
public void doInfinite ()
{
  //code
  synchronized (this)
  { 
    value = aValue;
  }
}
```

Comment: Considering the scenario a synchronized block would probably be sufficient.

Comment: Thanks to all, I can proceed now :-)

Answer (score 1):

Just because `Lock` is an interface and can't be instantiated. Use its subclasses.